# Chrome extension on www.google.com

Tags: google-chrome-extension

While learning chrome extensions, I tried to create a simple chrome extension that has a content script with a single alert statement. This works fine when I open www.google.co.in, I get the alert but when I open www.google.com, I am not getting the alert. Screenshots attached. What am I missing?

**Manifest:**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "My Cool Extension",
  "version": "0.1",
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["coolBackground.js"]
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "all_frames" : true,
      "matches": ["\u003Call_urls\u003E"],
      "js": ["coolContent.js"]    }
  ],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  }
}
```

**popup.html :**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hello World</title>
        <script src="coolBackground.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="popup.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 id="greeting">Hi!</h1>
        <input id="name" type="text" />
    </body>
</html>
```

**coolContent.js :**

```
alert("Hello world");
```

**coolBackground.js :**

```
console.log("background");
```

[image: screenshot of google.com]
[image: screenshot of google.in]

Comment: sorry about that.. I've corrected them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add proper permission in your manifest.json. See below an exanmple.

```
"permissions": [
    "*://*/*"
 ],
 "content_scripts" : [
    {
        "matches" : ["*://*/*"],
   .....
```

Comment: Try adding `"*://*/*"` in content_scripts -> matches . See my updated answer.

Comment: Ya.. Tried it as well.. still no alert... But, doesn't "*://*/*" and "\u003Call_urls\u003E" mean the same?

Comment: I just tried on my local machine and it is working as expected. No idea why it failing on your side.

Comment: Really? I've tried it in computers of different OS running different versions of chrome but still no +ve result. Can you tell me your OS and version of chrome you are running?

Comment: I am on Linux Ubuntu 14.04. Can you provide you original code as a gist - here https://gist.github.com/discover ?

Comment: The given code is working fine for me. I am guessing the alert popup may be disabled for google.com. Consider clearing the  cache and try again.

Comment: @elegant-user You are right. Can you please check the popup settings for google.com, as far as I remember you need to specifically give permission for popups for each site.

Comment: I've checked at the site-settings, everything is allowed. And I've tried clearing the cache as well.. Still the same.. no popup

Comment: Great, All the best!